# macOS Monterey --> fatal error: 'opencv2/videoio.hpp' file not found

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, macos-monterey

I am trying to build opencv on macOS for a CPP capstone project but when I try to compile like so:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_video=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_features2d=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_flann=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_highgui=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_ml=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_photo=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_shape=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_superres=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_ts=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_videostab=OFF ..

make -j8
```

I am getting the following error:

```
[ 98%] Built target opencv_model_diagnostics
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `zlib', needed by `lib/python3/cv2.cpython-39-darwin.so'.  Stop.
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
[ 98%] Building CXX object modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o
In file included from /Users/username/Projects/opencv/opencv/modules/python/src2/cv2.cpp:11:
In file included from /Users/username/Projects/opencv/opencv/build/modules/python_bindings_generator/pyopencv_generated_include.h:50:
/Users/username/Projects/opencv/opencv/modules/gapi/include/opencv2/gapi/streaming/cap.hpp:26:10: fatal error: 'opencv2/videoio.hpp' file not found
#include "opencv2/videoio.hpp"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/__/src2/cv2.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/python3/CMakeFiles/opencv_python3.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I did follow at first the instruction from [opencv](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d0/db2/tutorial_macos_install.html) but make step fails at:

```
[ 36%] Building CXX object modules/dnn/CMakeFiles/opencv_dnn.dir/int8layers/layers_common.avx512_skx.cpp.o
[ 36%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_dnn.dylib
[ 36%] Built target opencv_dnn
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: which version of opencv you are trying to install ? This seems opencv 3.0 or older

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk I am tying to install 4.5.5

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to build opencv without videio because I don't need it and need to reduce the image size, and cannot avoid this error with BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF

Comment: @JoeyGrisafe sorry for the late reply. Unfortunately, no, but I have a project which requires it and will try it again.

Comment: answered below @osterburg

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a workaround. You can turn off videoio if you also turn off gapi, like so:

```
-D BUILD_opencv_videoio=OFF -D BUILD_opencv_gapi=OFF
```

This will help reduce your build size.